# Exists function in update statement MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, exists

I got 2 tables:

`table0: (id,attr0,attr1)`

`table1: (id,attr0,attr1)`

I need to update `table0` with `table1` values, where `t0.id = t1.id`, using `exists` function (*avoid join function*).I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE table0
SET
    attr0   = trn.attr0,
    attr1   = trn.attr1
FROM( 
    SELECT id, max(transaction_date) as attr0,
    max(CASE 
            WHEN transaction_code in ('a', 'b', 'c')
            THEN transaction_date  
            ELSE NULL 
        END) as attr1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY id) trn
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table0.id = trn.id);
```

But this query updates all rows in `table0` and I don't understand why.
Plz, tell me, why does it work wrong?

Comment: `exists(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table0.id = trn.id)`  this part misses join predicate to `table1`.

Comment: Because you don't have any condition for table0 in FROM clause.

Comment: Please add some sample data. It's not quite clear why `But this query updates all rows` is incorrect behavior.

Comment: for example there are 10 rows in table0(id - from 0 to 9), nevertheless in result of 'FROM'(trn table) query there are olny 9 rows(id - from 0 to 8). And this statement updates all 10 rows in table0(row with id = 9 updates with random data). What sould i write in 'WHERE' condition ?

Comment: Please update your question with simple repro that is demonstrating this behavior. Sqlfiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this? This will only update the IDs from table1

```
with cte as (
SELECT id, max(transaction_date) as attr0,
max(CASE 
        WHEN transaction_code in ('a', 'b', 'c')
        THEN transaction_date  
        ELSE NULL 
    END) as attr1
    FROM table1 a

    GROUP BY id
    )
    update dbo.table0
    set
    attr0 = cte.attr0,
    attr1 = cte.attr1
    from cte where cte.id = table0.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
UPDATE t0
SET
    attr0   = trn.attr0,
    attr1   = trn.attr1
FROM table0 t0 join( 
    SELECT id, max(transaction_date) as attr0,
    max(CASE 
            WHEN transaction_code in ('a', 'b', 'c')
            THEN transaction_date  
            ELSE NULL 
        END) as attr1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY id)trn on trn.id=t0.id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Inner join you can update the data. like below.

```
UPDATE t
SET
    t.attr0   = trn.attr0,
    t.attr1   = trn.attr1
FROM( 
    SELECT id, max(transaction_date) as attr0,
    max(CASE 
            WHEN transaction_code in ('a', 'b', 'c')
            THEN transaction_date  
            ELSE NULL 
        END) as attr1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY id) trn
INNER JOIN table0 t ON t.id=trn.id
```